# How to check if all arrays in a struct have the same size

Tags: matlab

I have an 1xN-struct `myArr` (with `N` an undefined integer) that consists of a set of matrices. Those multidimensional arrays may have different sizes, but I only can perform certain tasks if they are all equal. How can I make that check?

Example:

```
mystruct = 

1x4 struct array with fields:
    Scalar
    Matrix
```

I wanted to know if the 2D-matrices of the field `Matrix`, which is a 2D-matrix, have the same length in the four structs. Is there any MATLAB function, or set of functions, to check this easily?

Thanks!

Comment: Please give a clearer example of your input and expected output.

Comment: @thewaywewalk If `size(mystruct.Matrix(1)) == size(mystruct.Matrix(2)) == size(mystruct.Matrix(3)) == size(mystruct.Matrix(4))` (sorry for the abuse of notation), it should return `1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `arrayfun` to compare against the `size` of the first element:

```
 tf = arrayfun( @(x)  isequal( size(x.Matrix), size(myArr(1).Matrix) ), myArr );
```

`tf` is true iff all `myArr.Matrix` have exactly the same `size`.

Note that it is more robust to use `isequal( size(x), size(y) )` than the check `all( size(x)==size(y) )` in case `x` and `y` have different number of dimmensions.

Comment: ah you beat me to it.

Comment: @Shai, I think you need to take the `all` function out of it. In this form you get an array not a scalar value.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is

```
sz=cellfun(@size, {myArr.Matrix}, 'uni', 0);
allEq = (numel(sz) <= 1) || isequal(sz{:});
```

`myArr.Matrix` expands to a comma-separated list and `isequal` can take multiple inputs.